# Callback issues error: invalid use of non-static data member

Tags: c++, class, oop, std

EDIT: Updated clean reproducible example.

I'm a beginner in C++ with a few years experience with C, so apologies if I am going about this the wrong way. I have tried to break down the issue to as small an example of code as I can. In my code I have inherited a C callback function and inside this I want to trigger another callback from a class member.

I am having two issues:

a) I don't have an instance of `Range` in `Callback` and the callback does not have a void * param for me to use.

b) I am getting an error message

> error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Range::cbk’

I'm just starting to learn C++ and the rules of OOP so apologies if I am doing things that are fundamentally flawed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Range
{
public:
  typedef std::function<void()> TCallback;
  TCallback cbk;

  Range()
  {
    cbk = std::bind(&Range::RunTest, this);
  }

  void Close() {}

  ~Range() { Close(); }

  void RunTest()
  {
        std::cout << "RunningTest\n";
  }
};

static void Callback(bool ev)
{
  if (ev)
    Range::cbk();
}


int main()
{
  std::function<void(bool)> test;
    Range r1;
  test = std::bind(Callback, 1);
  test(1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is your [MCVE]?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. As is currently, it is hard to understand what your problem may be. Is the problem that you are trying to call method, as a static method? If you are calling it from outside the `TestOne`, it is marked as `private`, as well, as being non-static.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Updated to break down issue to as small an example as I could.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Updated to break down issue to as small an example as I could

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking or what you're trying to do.

Comment: @KillzoneKid I want to be able to use the callback I set in my class

Comment: @KillzoneKid I did accidentally when making the edit removed now apologies

Comment: @tech1990 "_error: ‘cbk’ is not a member of ‘Range’_" Yes, `cbk` is not a member of `Range`. The only members `Range` has are: Constructor, destructor, `Close`, and `Run_test`. There is variable named `cbk`, which is local to the constructor, but it is not, as the error had stated, a member of `Range`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Ok and is there a way to do what I am trying to do. As I said in the description I am new to c++ so not aware if this is just not possible to do.

Comment: @tech1990 1) I doubt that the error, that you are, currently, asking about, is C++ specific, I think you can't do `void foo {int a;} void bar {a = 5;}` in C as well, which would trigger pretty much the same error, for pretty much the same reason. 2) "_is there a way to do what I am trying to do_" It's still, not quite clear enough what you want to do, but: yes.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius If I declare it outside the constructor I get an `error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Range::cbk’
`

Comment: @tech1990 "_If I declare it outside the constructor_" Unclear what, exactly, you declare outside of constructor.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius edits made to question

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a member function without an instance.

You did it right in the `Range` constructor; you did it wrong in `main` and `Callback`.

```
static void Callback(Range* ptr, bool ev)
{
  if (ev)
    ptr->cbk();
}
```

And:

```
test = std::bind(Callback, &r1, 1);
//                       ^^^^^
```

If you can't change `Callback`, then what you want to do is simply impossible. You'd have to have some *global* `Range` pointer, but this is really minging. Ultimately it's why classes were invented but if you can't use them because you're stuck with a really flat C API then you just have to hack around it like you would in C.

Comment: Thanks very much for the input; yes this is exactly the issue I can't change the declaration of Callback.
 I will probably go down the global pointer route even though I will need an array of global pointers for multiple instances.
As ugly as this it seems my only option.

Comment: @tech1990 Pretty much. As an aside the callback is poorly designed because, knowing that this was always a problem, people tended to at least stick a `void*` in there for passing information.